# Why am I unable to run the downloaded software for my printer (on Ubuntu) and how can I change this?

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner

I have a new Epson printer/scanner/copier/fax, model WF-7830. During set-up I downloaded the driver software for this model from the Epson website.

The message on the page for downloading the software says: "Install the software on your Windows computer and connect to the printer."

When I click on the software file in my folder, Archive Manager opens up and the window is completely blank, and the following message appears: "An error occurred while loading the archive."

My Ubuntu version is 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: You cannot use Windows drivers on Linux.

Comment: You usually don't need to install printer drivers on Linux. On Linux, the builtin CUPS software contains specifications for dealing with a large variety of printers

Comment: You are unable to run the downloaded software for your printer on Ubuntu because it is Windows software. You cannot change this.

Comment: Be aware that Linux uses 3 separate software systems for Print/Scan/FAX. "CUPS" for printing (see my answer below), "SANE" for scanning (see `man -k sane`, do `sudo sane-find-scanner`), and something else for FAX (see `man -k fax`).